# select the rows which has maximum a specific number of zeros

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, I want to choose the rows which has less than 3 zeros. For example, in the following df, only rows 2 has more than 3 zeros. The id columns is a constant column and I dont want to consider it.
'''

```
df['id'] = [1, 0, 2, 3]
df['a'] = [1, 2, 0,0]
df['b'] =[3, 0,0,0]
df['c'] = [4, 0, 0,1]
df['d'] = [0, 2, 3, 5]

   id   a   b   c   d
0   1   1   3   4   0
1   0   2   0   0   2
2   2   0   0   0   3
3   3   0   0   1   5
```

Out put:

```
   id   a   b   c   d
0   1   1   3   4   0
1   0   2   0   0   2
3   3   0   0   1   5
```

Comment: Variant of the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try `sum` the `0` count exclude `id` column on each row

```py
out = df[df.drop(columns='id').eq(0).sum(axis=1).lt(3)]
```

```
print(out)

   id  a  b  c  d
0   1  1  3  4  0
1   0  2  0  0  2
3   3  0  0  1  5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[(df == 0).iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1) < 3]

    id  a   b   c   d
0   1   1   3   4   0
1   0   2   0   0   2
3   3   0   0   1   5
```